# Record Powerpoint presentations with voice over

Tags: video, presentations, screen-recorder, microsoft-powerpoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free desktop recording / screencasting on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/201/free-desktop-recording-screencasting-on-windows)

I need to record (video) a Powerpoint presentation with an audio voice over. Do you have any software suggestions? Preferably free as it's a once off and it needs to support Windows.

**Edit:** Actually guys, this isn't a duplicate because the best answer to this question is that Powerpoint lets you record an audio narration over your Powerpoint presentations and then you can produce a slideshow file from your Powerpoint presentation which automatically loads and starts playing in Powerpoint when double-clicked on. Powerpoint lets you re-create the effect of a "video" without actually needing to create a video. So please re-open this question and allow relevant answers to Powerpoint to be added to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I got this thing set up for my mom over the summer, so I have experience :-).

If you only need video (for my mom the output was a 60MB Powerpoint with timed animations), this is easy. The best free solution is [Camstudio](http://camstudio.org/). Run the presentation with the microphone set up for it, and then just go through it.